# Spring WebApp Maven - Source folder is not on the Java build class path

Tags: java, maven-3, eclipse-classpath

I am following this [article](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/) to understand how to create a Java web application with Spring MVC.I created the web app project **CounterWebApp** at a separate location first
(**mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0**) and then imported the whole project in Eclipse.

I am having difficulty to put the **BaseController.java** in the correct package as stated in the article.It's either

1. "Source folder is not on the Java build class path",**OR**
2. BaseController.java is not getting created at the location 
   (**/src/main/java/com/mkyong/controller/BaseController.java**)

Please help me understand how to do it correctly ? Following are the contents of my **.classpath** file and **pom.xml** just after importing the project in eclipse.

### .classpath:

```
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-core/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-web/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-context/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-expression/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-expression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11-sources.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.sandeep</groupId>
        <artifactId>CounterWebApp</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>CounterWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <properties>
                <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
                <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
                <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>

                <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit.version}</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
                <finalName>CounterWebApp</finalName>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>3.0</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                                        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Configure Project as maven project in Eclipse. Right Click Project Configure->Maven Project

Comment: @jaipster Excuse my ignorance,can you please explain the reason as to why do I need to configure it to a Maven project as the article clearly states at Step 3: "You want Eclipse web project....."

Comment: So that eclipse is able to reference this project libraries from m2 repo and understand its project structure. Secondly a web project can also be maven project. I had myself downloaded and used this project a few weeks back to build my application.

Comment: I have added how the problem got resolved as an answer.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

### **How the problem was resolved:**

1. Created a folder "java" under "main"(File -> New -> Folder).After this step,we have 3 folders under src/main: java,resources,webapp.
2. I downloaded the .zip provided along with the article,compared the .classpath with mine and modified it accordingly.

At this point,my eclipse.classpath content looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-core/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-web/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-context/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-expression/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-expression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11-sources.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

Finally.created the Spring MVC controller class BaseController.java(**/src/main/java/com/sandeep/controller/BaseController.java**)

- Select "java",New -> Other -> Class -> Next.
- Package:        com.sandeep.controller
- Name:       BaseController