# servlet-class references to "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" that does not implement interface javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, spring-3, servlet-2.5

I am new to Spring and trying to deploy and run my first spring web application using Maven.For more details,please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958321/spring-webapp-maven-source-folder-is-not-on-the-java-build-class-path/21965202#21965202)(**a question I posted yesterday**):

Now,the problem I am having is: When I am trying the follwing 2 URL's,I am getting an 
HTTP Status 404 - Resource not available.

```
http://localhost:8080/CounterWebApp/welcome
http://localhost:8080/CounterWebApp/welcome/sandeep
```

Tomcat Server Console Warning message:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request URI [/CounterWebApp/welcome]
No mapping found for HTTP request URI [/CounterWebApp/welcome/sandeep]
```

This is the relevant portion of my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**Here I am having a warning :**

```
servlet-class references to "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" that does not implement interface javax.servlet.Servlet
```

### Controller class:

```
package com.sandeep.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Maven Web Project + Spring 3 MVC - welcome()");

        //Spring uses InternalResourceViewResolver and return back index.jsp
        return "index";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomeName(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Maven Web Project + Spring 3 MVC - " + name);
        return "index";

    }

}
```

What is it that I am missing out? Please help.

### Edit:

### web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

### mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And I have this **index.jsp** inside /WEB-INF/pages/.

### pom.xml(servlet api dependency)

```
<!--Servlet API Dependency-->
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
```

Comment: I hope you have servlet-mapping defined as well. Can you show the servlet-mapping part of your web.xml?

Comment: Do you have multiple copies of servlet-api.jar?

Comment: @sakura/@EJP - I have edited my question and added the information. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

The **base-package** value in **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml** was incorrect.

I had to correct it and then - build,deploy and run. :)

### mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml(final)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.sandeep.controller" />

        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

Here is the entire [documentation](http://tinyurl.com/MavenWebApp) :)

Comment: The documentation is not available anymore (invalid dropbox link)

Comment: @Kashban Thanks for pointing out. Fixed the invalid link issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your URL Pattern from

`<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

To

`<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

It should work.

Comment: Tried that followed by "mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0","mvn package",deploy and run => Didn't work.

Comment: Is it the same issue i.e. "No mapping found for HTTP request URI" ?

Comment: Yes,the same: 
No mapping found for HTTP request URI [/CounterWebApp/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name mvc-dispatcher

Comment: Problem solved.I have added it as an answer along with the documentation. Thank you. :)